# AWS DMS (Database Migration Service) SQL Server to SQL Server not replicating changes

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, transactional-replication, aws-dms

I have 2 AWS SQL Servers (as RDS instances) in the same VPC, however one is in a private subnet (the source) and one is in a public subnet (the target). I am replicating FROM SQL Server Standard Edition TO SQL Server Web Edition.

I have set up DMS (Database Migration Service) between them to do a full table load, then replicate ongoing changes. The initial load occurs without issue, however ongoing changes are not repicated. When I check the table status, I can see that the last updated date-time is continually updating, however as you can see, there are no inserts or updates being tracked. These figures remain 0.

[image]

The status of the migration task is: Load complete, replication ongoing
The source database backup model is FULL (Was SIMPLE, but realised this wouldn't work so it's been changed to FULL).

The CloudWatch log is just repeats of the below:

```
2019-03-02T23:13:22 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Throughput monitor: Last DB time scanned: 2019-03-03T10:12:37.947. Last LSN scanned: 00065a3e:00030286:0003. #scanned events: 183. (sqlserver_log_utils.c:4565)
2019-03-02T23:15:22 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Throughput monitor: Last DB time scanned: 2019-03-03T10:15:04.940. Last LSN scanned: 00065a3e:0003040e:0003. #scanned events: 413. (sqlserver_log_utils.c:4565)
2019-03-02T23:17:22 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Throughput monitor: Last DB time scanned: 2019-03-03T10:16:54.523. Last LSN scanned: 00065a3e:00030463:0003. #scanned events: 188. (sqlserver_log_utils.c:4565)
2019-03-02T23:19:22 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Throughput monitor: Last DB time scanned: 2019-03-03T10:19:12.697. Last LSN scanned: 00065a3e:0003053d:0003. #scanned events: 402. (sqlserver_log_utils.c:4565)
2019-03-02T23:21:22 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Throughput monitor: Last DB time scanned: 2019-03-03T10:21:22.300. Last LSN scanned: 00065a3e:000305d3:0003. #scanned events: 225. (sqlserver_log_utils.c:4565)
```

Which is different to when the full load occurs when the task is started, which details many tables being copied across etc. I've stop/started the task, I've tried changing the behavior from truncating target tables to drop and re-create etc, but none of this has any effect. There is no 'last failure message' listed in the Dashboard, nor is there any CDC start position or recovery checkpoint:

```
Change data capture (CDC)
Change data capture (CDC) start position
-
Change data capture (CDC) recovery checkpoint
-
```

Task status never seems to change from CHANGE_PROCESSING

```
server_name task_name   task_status status_time pending_changes disk_swap_size  task_memory source_current_position source_current_timestamp    source_tail_position    source_tail_timestamp   source_timestamp_applied
localhost.localdomain   TIXLNKU6OELULHNTU2G5IABSF4  CHANGE PROCESSING   2019-03-02 23:25:12 0   0   927 00065a3e:000306a5:0003  2019-03-02 23:25:11 000659f3:00000540:0004  2019-03-02 08:37:28 1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

There are no errors in awsdms_apply_exceptions.

Can someone please assist as to why replication is not occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is quite simple - the Web edition of SQL Server cannot be a valid target for replication via DMS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I understand that you have to include the source table into a publication in your SQL Server source and enable the change tra:

[image: Detail of the publication]
[image: Detail of enabled CDC database option]